# How to create unit test for http request in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I am trying to create a unit test for a random generate url.

My item Controller JS

```
init()

function init(){
   var results = itemService.request();    
   other codes..
}
```

My itemService js

```
function request(){
    other codes..
    return $http.get(url);
}

function generateUrl() {
    var url = 'https://project/'
    var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    url += num;
    other codes to generate more attribute for url…

    return url
}
```

Unit test:

```
beforeEach(function () {
        module(‘itemApp’);

        inject(function ($injector) {
            $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
            itemService = $injector.get(‘itemService’);
            $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
        });

        vm.$controller(‘itemCtrl’, {
            ‘$scope’:$scope
        })

     $httpBackend.when('GET', 'https://project/15/other-attributes').respond(200);
});

 describe('initialization', function() {      
       it(‘start init’ , function(){
            //not sure what to do.
       });
```

The application works but I am getting

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET https://project/12/other-attributes
```

when I ran the unit test because I will have random numbers in my url.

I am not sure how to mock the url because it generates randomly. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this,

```
$httpBackend.when('GET', /https:\/\/project\/[0-9]+\/other-attributes/).respond(200);
```

$httpBackend.when() method does support regex.

In case of dynamic environment variables,

```
var environmentUrl = "http://google.com";
$httpBackend.when('GET', new RegExp(environmentUrl + '/[0-9]+/other-attributes')).respond(200);
```

Comment: Thank you. What if my https : // project is a environement variable and my actual code is like 
$httpBackend.when('GET', environmentUrl + \/[0-9]+\/other-attributes/).respond(200); How should I produce regex for it?

Comment: In that case, you can always use the Javascript RegExp method, I have updated it in the above answer.